# Is there a DLL I can use to interpret Python?

Tags: python, dll, game-maker

So I was thinking it would be awfully convenient to have a Python interpreter DLL, and to what I know, the interpreter is a DLL, but I don't know how to use it/if it can be used that way.

I want to execute python files from Gamemaker Studio through a DLL, (Python 2.7, preferably.) and if I knew the functions of the DLL, I could make the proper GML scripts to do it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It is called *embedding* the Python interpreter. Read the section on [*extending and embedding the Python interpreter*](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) of the Python documentation.

You might consider some other interpreter, in particular [Lua](http://lua.org/), which is free software, widely used in games, and rumored to be faster, or [GUILE](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) (also faster, and with a much more powerful and expressive language, [Scheme](http://schemers.org/); read also [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/))